# Is $2^{1/n} < 1 + \frac1n$ for all $n > 1$?

Tags: calculus

If so, why? Can you show it using the binomial theorem?

If not, how can you prove it?

Comment: What have YOU tried? Also, try to think of REALLY REALLY REALLY large values of $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Try the binomial theorem!  Raise both sides to the nth and compare.

$(1 + 1/n)^n = 1 + n(1/n) + (1/n)^2 {n \choose 2} +.... > 1 + n(1/n) = 1 + 1 = 2$

If we accept $b^n > a^n => b > a$ (which we can if a and b are greater than one) so

$(1 + 1/n)^n > 2 => [(1 + 1/n)^n]^{1/n} = 1 + 1/n > 2^{1/n}$

Answer (score 1):

A version of the Bernoulli inequality says that, for $x>-1$ and $n>1$,
$$
(1+x)^n>1+nx
$$
Since $1/n>-1$, we conclude that
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n}>1+n\frac{1}{n}=1+1=2
$$